# How to use the for range loop in django admin?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I need something like `forloop.counter` in **templates**.
Is this possible?

Comment: Hi there!  forloop.counter is actually made for templates, using django's template language.  Is there specific problem you need help with?  Reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, but i want use for range loop in admin.py

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve in the admin with a forloop counter?

Comment: @MiloPersic I want to have numbering for the rows of my model

Comment: Understood.  Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135954/generate-row-numbers-for-django-admin-listview-for-an-app

Comment: Awesome! Congratulations!